# Autolayout: Can't resize window after setting constraints

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout

i need some help with auto-layout setting programatically. I have a view that I set into another view that is managed by storyboard.

```
var content = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 3000, height: self.view.frame.height))
[...]
scrollingView.documentView = content
```

Than i add the pin constraints that the view will always be top to bottom:

```
    let topPinContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: contentView
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top
        , relatedBy: .Equal
        , toItem: contentView.superview
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top
        , multiplier: 1.0
        , constant: 0
    )
    let bottomPinContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(
          item: contentView
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom
        , relatedBy: .Equal
        , toItem: contentView.superview
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom
        , multiplier: 1.0
        , constant: 0
    )
    let heightContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: contentView
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height
        , relatedBy: .Equal
        , toItem: contentView.superview
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height
        , multiplier: 1.0
        , constant: 0
    )

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
          topPinContraints
        , bottomPinContraints
        , heightContraints
    ])

    contentView.needsLayout = true
```

After NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints the view is filled from top to bottom in the superview, **but** the window is not resizable in height anymore.
I can resize it in width, but the height is now fixed.

How do I add a top and bottom pin without loosing the resize possibilities?

Thanks a lot,

ps.

Comment: Are `content` (in your first snippet) and `contentView` (in your second) the same thing? Have you set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false on the view? Also, if the `documentView` is pinned to its superview, which is the clip view, in what circumstances will the scroll view scroll? That is, when will the document view not be the same size as the scroll view's content size?

Comment: Hi Ken, yes, and sry. contentView = view, because i orderd it into a func:  func autoLayout(contentView: NSView){}. When I set contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false, than the view disappears completely.

Comment: i can set heightContraints and widthtContraints with no contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints, but than the scrollview is not working anymore, because width is than contentView.superview!.frame.with i suppose.  :-(

Comment: one last thing: i can calculate the with _let calculatedWith: CGFloat = (CGFloat) (contentView.subviews.count * 130)_ because my subviews have a fixed size. But how to update the constraints? I can't call my _autoLayout_ function twice, because of an _NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints_ error.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i had some code that works for me. But is it the right solution? Let me post my whole ViewController to show you my experience. Maybe you can post your comments what I can make better.

```
import Foundation
import Cocoa

class ColoumnMasterViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollingView: NSScrollView!

var position = 0
var contentView: NSView?
var widthtContraints: NSLayoutConstraint?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    contentView = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 3000, height: self.view.frame.height))

    contentView!.wantsLayer = true
    contentView!.layer?.backgroundColor =  NSColor.redColor().CGColor

    add()
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.6, target: self, selector: Selector("add"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    scrollingView.documentView = contentView

    autoLayout(contentView!)
}

func add(){
    println("add view on position \(position)")
    let vc: NSViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("coloumn_view_controller") as! NSViewController
    vc.view.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: (position++ * 130), y: 0))
    vc.view.setFrameSize(NSSize(width: 130, height: self.view.frame.height))
    contentView!.addSubview(vc.view)

    updateWidth()
}

func autoLayout(contentView: NSView){
    let topPinContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: contentView
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top
        , relatedBy: .Equal
        , toItem: contentView.superview
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top
        , multiplier: 1.0
        , constant: 0
    )
    let bottomPinContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(
          item: contentView
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom
        , relatedBy: .Equal
        , toItem: contentView.superview
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom
        , multiplier: 1.0
        , constant: 0
    )

    println("heightContraints \(contentView.superview!.frame.height)")
    let heightContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: contentView
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height
        , relatedBy: .Equal
        , toItem: contentView.superview!
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height
        , multiplier: 1.0
        , constant: 0
    )
    println("widthtContraints \(contentView.superview!.frame.width)")
    let calculatedWith: CGFloat = (CGFloat) (contentView.subviews.count * 130)
    widthtContraints = NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: contentView
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width
        , relatedBy: .Equal
        , toItem: nil
        , attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width
        , multiplier: 1.0
        , constant: 0
    )
    widthtContraints!.constant = calculatedWith

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
          topPinContraints
         , bottomPinContraints
         , heightContraints
         , widthtContraints!
    ])

    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.needsLayout = true

}

func updateWidth(){
    let calculatedWith: CGFloat = (CGFloat) (contentView!.subviews.count * 130)
    if (widthtContraints != nil) {
        widthtContraints!.constant = calculatedWith
    }
}

}
```

Thanks thousand times,

ps

Comment: Setting `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to false worked for me. Thanks!